# how to take href into a variable and give it to href="$vrable so"

Tags: php, html

```
<?php if (!empty($this->highlitsrightside)) {   foreach ($this->highlitsrightside as $rightsidehlights){ if (!empty($rightsidehlights['highimage1']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage2']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage3']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage4']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage5'])) { ?>
           <?php $hrf1 = "<?php echo SERVICES . 'righthighlights/?highrid=' . $rightsidehlights['highlightid'];?>"; ?>

              <?php } else { $hrf1 = '#';} ?>
          <?php if (!empty($rightsidehlights['icontext'])) {?>

            <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="$hrf1" data-options="" tabindex="0"><i class="<?php echo $rightsidehlights['icontext']; ?>" ></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>
            <?php  } else {?> 

<a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="$hrf" data-options="" tabindex="0"> <img style=" display: inline-block;" src="<?php echo UPLOADS . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $rightsidehlights['highlighticon'] ?>"width="30" height="16"  ></span></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>

            <?php } }?>
```

[image]

Comment: You mean need to redirect to href page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the open and close PHP tags appropriately.

```
    <?php 
    if (!empty($this->highlitsrightside)) {   
        foreach ($this->highlitsrightside as $rightsidehlights)
        { 

        if (!empty($rightsidehlights['highimage1']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage2']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage3']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage4']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage5'])) {
            $hrf1 = "www.google.com";
        } else { 
            $hrf1 = '#';
        }
        if (!empty($rightsidehlights['icontext'])) {
            echo '';
    ?>
            <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?php echo $hrf1; ?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"><i class="<?php echo $rightsidehlights['icontext']; ?>" ></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>
    <?php  
        } else {?> 
            <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?php echo $hrf1; ?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"> <img style=" display: inline-block;" src="<?php echo UPLOADS . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $rightsidehlights['highlighticon'] ?>"width="30" height="16"  ></span></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>
    <?php
                 }
         }

    } ?>
```

To remove the confusion this script can be as simple as:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($this->highlitsrightside)) {   
    foreach ($this->highlitsrightside as $rightsidehlights){ 
        if (!empty($rightsidehlights['highimage1']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage2']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage3']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage4']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage5'])) {
            $hrf1 = "www.google.com";
        } else { 
            $hrf1 = '#';
        }
        if (!empty($rightsidehlights['icontext'])) {
            echo '<a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="'.$hrf1.'" data-options="" tabindex="0"><i class="'.$rightsidehlights['icontext'].'" ></i>'.$rightsidehlights['highlightname'].'</a>';
        }else{
            echo '<a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="'.$hrf1.'" data-options="" tabindex="0"> <img style=" display: inline-block;" src="'.UPLOADS . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $rightsidehlights['highlighticon'].'"width="30" height="16"  ></span></i> '.$rightsidehlights['highlightname'].'</a>'; 
        }
    }
} 

?>
```

Comment: still error uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::index() in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: href="<?php echo SERVICES . 'righthighlights/?highrid=' . $rightsidehlights['highlightid'];?>"THIS IS THE PROBLEM ACTUALLY -----THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR SHORTING MY CODE

Comment: No problem, if this fixed your question, mark this as the answer. If you have another issue just post another question if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use PHP tag for that inside HTML as I have done in your code.
example

```
<a href="<?=$hrf1?>" > </a>
```

below is your code

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($this->highlitsrightside)) {   
        foreach ($this->highlitsrightside as $rightsidehlights)
        { 

        if (!empty($rightsidehlights['highimage1']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage2']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage3']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage4']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage5'])) { ?>
               <?php $hrf1 = "www.google.com"; ?>

                  <?php } else { $hrf1 = '#';} ?>
              <?php if (!empty($rightsidehlights['icontext'])) {?>

                <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?=$hrf1?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"><i class="<?php echo $rightsidehlights['icontext']; ?>" ></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>
                <?php  } else {?> 

                <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?=$hrf1?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"> <img style=" display: inline-block;" src="<?php echo UPLOADS . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $rightsidehlights['highlighticon'] ?>"width="30" height="16"  ></span></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>

                <?php
                 }
         }


    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below

```
<?php if (!empty($this->highlitsrightside)) {   foreach ($this->highlitsrightside as $rightsidehlights){ if (!empty($rightsidehlights['highimage1']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage2']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage3']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage4']) || !empty($rightsidehlights['highimage5'])) { ?>

        <?php  $hrf1 = SERVICES.'righthighlights/?highrid='.$rightsidehlights['highlightid']; ?>

              <?php } else { $hrf1 = '#';} ?>
          <?php if (!empty($rightsidehlights['icontext'])) {?>

            <a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?php echo $hrf1; ?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"><i class="<?php echo $rightsidehlights['icontext']; ?>" ></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>
            <?php  } else {?> 

<a class="off_clr_text link_chn_lo" href="<?php echo $hrf; ?>" data-options="" tabindex="0"> <img style=" display: inline-block;" src="<?php echo UPLOADS . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $rightsidehlights['highlighticon'] ?>"width="30" height="16"  ></span></i> <?php echo $rightsidehlights['highlightname']; ?></a>

            <?php } }  ?>
```